# Android ProgressBar: sometimes aren't shown in 2.3.6

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a screen with several chronometers counting backwards. Each chrono has its own `ProgressBar` to represent how much is left until reaching 0 (the `ProgressBar` starts full). This `Activity` works great in `Android` 4, but today I tried it in `Android` 2.3.6 and sometimes the `ProgressBars` aren't shown.

Here are some use cases so you can understand in which ones it's not working as it should. In all cases the ProgressBars should be shown.

-User opens the `Activity` for first time, all `ProgressBars` need to be full and not running. `ProgressBars` aren't shown.

-**Some** `ProgressBars` start running (decreasing). They are still not shown. If the user closes the `app` and opens it again, **all** the `ProgressBars` are shown (even the ones that are full).

-When some chronometer reaches 0 its `ProgressBar` is filled again and its inner color is changed to red. When that happens the `ProgressBar` disappears too.

Anybody knows why would that be?

This is how I declare the `ProgressBars` in my xml:

```
         <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/lci_progbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lci_time"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:maxHeight="20dip"
                android:minHeight="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/time_progressbar" />
```

This is what I do in my Activity:

```
    // Initialize progress bar.
    progBars[i] = (ProgressBar) findViewById(ids[i]);
    if (progBars[i].getAnimation() != null)
        progBars[i].getAnimation().cancel();

    if (arr_Chronometers[i].isCountingReverse()) {
        // Chrono hasn't reached 0.
        progBars[i].setMax((int) arr_Chronometers[i].doGetTotalTime());
        progBars[i].setProgress((int) arr_Chronometers[i].doGetElapsedTime());
        progBars[i].setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.time_progressbar)); // Green bar
    }
    else {
        // Chrono has reached 0.
        progBars[i].setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.time_progressbar_red)); // Red bar

        progBars[i].setMax(100);
        progBars[i].setProgress(100);
    }
```

Like I said, it works on Android 4 (4.0.4 and 4.2), but doesn't work on Android 2.3.6 (I tried it in a couple devices and in emulator).

Thanks!

Comment: There's not much in your snippets which is Android version specific. However, you're setting both a `progressDrawable` _and_ an `indeterminateDrawable` which makes no sense, at least not if I understand your scenario right. If I were you I'd only set the `progressDrawable` in the XML and also the initial and max value. Maybe you're confusing older Android versions with this somewhat contradictory initialization.